# excel vba - Inserting sheetname into a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

trying to fill a range of blank cells with the name of the sheet that they are in. not sure why Range("ActiveSheet.Name") does not work? any help appreciated!

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B1:B100")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Range("ActiveSheet.Name")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use Range.... just use this:

```
cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
If cell.value <> "" Then
    cell.Offset(0, -1) = ActiveSheet.name
End If
```

If you decide to get away from the ActiveSheet, this way is a bit fancier:

```
   cell.Offset(0, -1) = rng.Parent.name
```

or

```
   cell.Offset(0, -1) = cell.Parent.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Sheets(i).Name` where i equals the number of the sheet instead of `Range("ActiveSheet.Name)`